# Can i delete/hide specific chart grid line?

Tags: c#, mschart

I want to delete/hide specific ms chart gridline, is that possible?

[image]

Comment: you want to delete everything after the blue line right ?

Comment: No, that is not possible. The only workarounds I can think of would to either remove them all and draw them in a xxxPaint event or to try overdrawing that gridline in a paint event or overlaying a some element like an annotation or a stripline. Hardly worth the effort, imo.. But maybe setting the y-axis minmum would prevent the whole issue??

Comment: yes, i want to delete everything after the blue line

Comment: I've tried to drawline in the paint event but it's gone when I use "chart.printing.printpaint()", the line is not drawed in the print document.

Comment: That is right, you probably would have to do some more in the print event. Overlaying a white  HorizontalLineAnnotation could do the job.

Comment: Correction: RectangleAnnotation will work better than  LineAnnotation. If you want to I can post an example..

Comment: yes i want to try that, thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that covers a part of the chartarea with a white [RectangleAnnotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.rectangleannotation?view=netframework-4.7.2).

[image]

```
// a few references:
ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
// create an annotation
var ra = new RectangleAnnotation();
// by default anotations are positioned in percentages
// we associate it with axes to change positioning to axis values:
ra.AxisX = ax;
ra.AxisY = ay;
// our colors:
ra.LineColor = Color.White;
// for testing I use a semi-transparent color:
ra.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(222, Color.White);
// the values of the last point in my series:
double vxLast = chart.Series[0].Points.Last().XValue;
double vyLast = chart.Series[0].Points.Last().YValues[0];
// the top right of the chartarea:
double vxEnd = ax.Maximum;
double vyEnd = ay.Maximum;
// we position the annotation
ra.X = vxLast;
ra.Y = vyEnd;
// by default annotations are as large as we set them to be
// I cheat by clipping it to my chartarea:
ra.ClipToChartArea = ca.Name;
// now it is enough to make them really large:
ra.Width = 9999;
ra.Height = 9999;
// done. now we show it:
chart.Annotations.Add(ra);
```

Of course you can calculate the exact width and height if you want to..

Annoations should print and will be saved, scaled etc..